# Specflow External steps assembly - No matching step definition found for one or more steps

Tags: specflow

Using VS 2015, Specflow 2.2 and MSTest.

I have a test project containing a feature file, the steps are contained in a library project (that compiles to LCC.Integration.Common.Components.dll) of the same solution. There's a project reference from the test project to the library project.

The app.config file of the test project contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
    </configSections>
    <specFlow>
        <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
        <stepAssemblies>
            <stepAssembly assembly="LCC.Integration.Common.Components" />
        </stepAssemblies>
        <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
    </specFlow>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

At design time, the binding from the feature to the steps seems to work fine:

[image: so1]

I can right-click any step within the feature, select "Go to Step Definition" and the navigation to the correct step within the library project works fine.

However, when I run the test, the test explorer shows the test as "Skipped" with the following message: "Assert.Inconclusive failed. No matching step definition found for one or more steps"

Comment: Is the step assembly in the output dir of your test project?

Comment: It is in the GAC - shouldn’t it find it there?

Comment: I don't think so. We are using Assembly.LoadFrom(<filename>) to load the step assemblies. I don't think this method is looking in the GAC.

Comment: ah interesting! Could you please explain where you've added the Assembly.LoadFrom ?

Comment: Ok, it's a Assembly.Load in https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/TestRunnerManager.cs#L87

Comment: hmm, this is strange - it seems the build / test process doesn't even reach the point where the \TestResults\Out folder is populated. The test solution containing the specflow test does compile ok and I can navigate from the feature file to the steps of the external project by hitting F12

Comment: Did this issue get resolved? I am having similar issues and do not know how to proceed.